# Weird Object Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

First, I'm not a javascript developer so I don't have a great deal of experience in this if any.

I have a footer I'm inserting into an HTML page using jQuery that has the following code in it that per the client "NEEDS TO BE THERE".

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
//--></script>
```

I don;t really have to worry about anything except this s.t(); line of code.  I need to write a dummy Object or whatever else and include it in the header that doesn't do anything per se except prevent a javascript error from occurring.

So really I need "s" the object to be instantiated and have a function "t" attached to it that basically does nothing.

Any help is appreciated.  This isn't something I want to do but given the budget and project constraints of the client I just need for this to work without a javascritp error.

thanks if you can help.

Comment: That is Omniture's code. http://www.omniture.com/en/

Comment: This piece of code is the basic code for Omniture SiteCatalyst. You must include the s_code.js. Otherwise, the code you showed is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = {
   t: function(){}
};
```

See it in, hmm, action: http://jsbin.com/oboju

In case you're worried `s` is defined and don't want to override it, you can check for it first (this doesn't cover the case `s.t` is defined but isn't a function):

```
if(!s){ // check if s exists
  var s = [];
}
if(!s.t){ // check if s has t
  s.t = function(){};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript prototype:

```
function s () {
}

function doSomething () {
}

s.prototype.t = doSomething;
```

edit: typo

Comment: This isn't complete, you cannot write `s.t();` - s isn't a variable. it should be `var s2=new s(); s2.t();`, so you may want to change `s`'s name.

Comment: Yeah, was only thinking about providing the object that he has to use.